# Hide parameter from Swagger (Swashbuckle)

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-5, swashbuckle

I have a C# .NET 5.0 ASP.NET Core Web API application with "Enable OpenAPI support" selected. I want to hide the `optional` parameter in the below example from what shows up on the swagger page. I have found numerous posts about hiding a property or the controller but none of these solutions seem to work for just the parameter in the given code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string query, string optional = "")
{
   return OK();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a custom attibute and an operation filter inhering from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter to exclude the desired parameters from swagger.json generation

```
public class OpenApiParameterIgnoreAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

public class OpenApiParameterIgnoreFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiOperation operation, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation == null || context == null || context.ApiDescription?.ParameterDescriptions == null)
            return;

        var parametersToHide = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
            .Where(parameterDescription => ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute(parameterDescription))
            .ToList();

        if (parametersToHide.Count == 0)
            return;

        foreach (var parameterToHide in parametersToHide)
        {
            var parameter = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(parameter => string.Equals(parameter.Name, parameterToHide.Name, System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
            if (parameter != null)
                operation.Parameters.Remove(parameter);
        }
    }

    private static bool ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.ApiParameterDescription parameterDescription)
    {
        if (parameterDescription.ModelMetadata is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            return metadata.Attributes.ParameterAttributes.Any(attribute => attribute.GetType() == typeof(OpenApiParameterIgnoreAttribute));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Put it in your controller's parameter

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string query, [OpenApiParameterIgnore] string optional = "")
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Then configure it in Status.cs

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API Title", Version = "v1" });
        c.OperationFilter<OpenApiParameterIgnoreFilter>();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for including the "Put it in your controller's parameter" part! I didn't (well still don't) understand how `OpenApiParameterIgnore` is referenced anywhere else in the code you provided. I'm guessing it is from `OpenApiParameterIgnoreAttribute` and the `Attribute` part is implied?

Comment: Yes, the Attribute suffix is implied by the compiler. By naming convention Microsoft suggest to ends custom class with the name of the base class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: The ignore filter works when the attribute is directly in the method parameter list, but it doesn't work when the parameter is a complex type and the attribute is inside a complex type that should be ignored. How does the code need to be changed to make it work for that case?

Comment: If metadata.Attributes.ParameterAttributes is changed to metadata.Attributes.Attributes it works also inside a class.